# apache .htaccess show directory index only to authenticated user

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, configuration

i have this directory structure on my web server:

```
web
    privatedir1
    privatedir2
    publicdir
        file1
        file2
        file3
```

i want to set the following functionality using .htaccess files:

- user 'admin' (authenticated) has unlimited access to all dirs (incl. dir indexes)
- anyone else can download file1, file2, file3 but can not see listing (index) of publicdir

can you please describe how to achieve this with .htaccess files?
i know how to allow/disallow directory indexes but i can't figure out how to do it conditionaly (depending on whether the user is authenticated or not)

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic example, but that's how you can do it.

```
<Directory /srv/dev/>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Indexes

        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /srv/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/dev/apps/>
        <If "%{REQUEST_URI} != '/'">
        Require all granted
        </If>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your answer might lie at this URL

[htaccess allow access to specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623019/htaccess-allow-access-to-specific-user)

"You'll need to create a user database/specific user you want to allow with the htpasswd utility. From there, in your htaccess file in the directory you want to limit, use:"

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Authorization Form Title"
AuthType Basic

#Allow any valid user
require valid-user

#Allow only one user with specified username
require user username
```

"More information can be found at plenty of online references, this is one of the first that came up: http://www.apacheweek.com/features/userauth"